# Displaying labels on x-axis with "yearmon" variable (ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, zoo, yearmonth

I am trying to display all month values on my x-axis, which is formatted as a "yearmon" variable

My data are structured as follows:

## Print data example

```
dput(collective_action_monthly[1:4, ])
```

ouptut:

```
structure(list(collective_action = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), treatment_details = c("pre", 
"pre", "pre", "pre"), month_year = structure(c(2011.41666666667, 
2011.75, 2011.83333333333, 2011.91666666667), class = "yearmon"), 
    n = c(22L, 55L, 15L, 207L), collective_action_percentage = c(0.0124223602484472, 
    0.031055900621118, 0.00846979107848673, 0.116883116883117
    ), am = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("post", "pre"
    ), class = "factor")), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), groups = structure(list(
    treatment_details = "pre", .rows = structure(list(1:4), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -1L), .drop = TRUE))
```

This my code to visualize the trend using bar graphs by month:

```
ggplot(data = collective_action_monthly, aes(x = month_year, y = collective_action_percentage)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position=position_dodge()) + 
    scale_fill_grey() +
    ylab("percentage") + 
    theme(text=element_text(size=10)) + 
    theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold")) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format(accuracy = 1)) +
   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5)) +
  theme_bw()
```

which produces:
[image]

However, rather than only showing three months in the x-axis, I would like to show all months. I also tried adding "scale_x_continuous(labels = 0:14, breaks = 0:14) " to the code above, but it still does not display months:
[image]

Ideally, I would like to produce a graph as the one below, but with months instead of years.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ggplot` doesn't have a `yearmon` scale built in--looks like the `zoo` package does, but it doesn't have a convenient way to specify "breaks every month"--so I would suggest converting to `Date` class and using `scale_x_date`. I've deleted most of your `theme` stuff to make the changes I've made more obvious (the theming didn't seem relevant to the issue).

```
ggplot(data = collective_action_monthly, aes(x = as.Date(month_year), y = collective_action_percentage)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position=position_dodge()) + 
    scale_fill_grey() +
    scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%b %Y") +
    ylab("percentage") + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Presumably `yearmon` is from the `zoo` package, which as you guessed has a `scale_x_yearmon`. I've added an answer to demonstrate, but I think if I were doing it myself, I would probably convert to standard dates too.

Comment: I wouldn't.  That would make the X axis irregularly spaced so it is basically wrong.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I'm confused--do you think this answer creates a misleading or wrong plot? Could you help me understand what's wrong about it?

Comment: To me, it looks identical to the `scale_x_yearmon` version in Allan's answer, except that axis limits match the range of the data.

Comment: It looks similar but the analyses associated with it likely all assume regularly spaced data.  It is actually easier to do it right rather than switching systems just for the axis.

Comment: I'm not suggesting changing the class for any analysis--and I don't see an easier way to adjust the plot axis as OP asks.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, Allan's answer keeps the `yearmon` class but puts it on a regularly spaced axis with `breaks = seq(2011.25, 2012, 1/12)`. Less convenient code--needing to explicitly set the limits--for the same result.

Comment: Well, if you don't like the default obviously you will have to specify something else.  Also I don't see any good reason to start at April when there is no data for April. and May.  If we can omit these months then specifying `scale_x_yearmon(n = 12)` or any large number for n is all that is needed.

Comment: `scale_x_yearmon(n = 12)` looks great, you should add it as an answer!

Answer (score 2):

The `zoo` packages includes `scale_x_yearmon`, so you can do:

```r
library(zoo)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = collective_action_monthly, 
       aes(x = month_year, y = collective_action_percentage)) +
    geom_col(position = position_dodge(preserve = "single")) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1),
                       name = "percentage") +
    scale_x_yearmon(breaks = seq(2011.25, 2012, 1/12),
                    limits = c(2011.25, 2012)) +
    theme_bw(base_size = 10) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold"),
          axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]